# How to change text of a label in Eclipse using Java

Tags: java, eclipse

This link will take you to a picture of my code, with the program running, and what is displayed in the console.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQraW.jpg

I've written a test to the console to show me that the variables are infact correct and loading the correct thing. Which is clearly working. The only thing not working correctly and im 100% sure the code is correct is the labels. change the text of a label doesnt seem to work and i cannot figure out why. Ive tried changing them to static, tried get and setting, i've tried for a few hours to find other solutions and asking this question is my last resort. lol.

EDIT : Hopefully this is enough code for yall to understand now. It's 3 classes. I launch from CoPrjGUI, i type what i want to search for in the text field, it populates a combobox when i click Find, then i click Download to populate my main page with the one query found. then i click Start to load a summary of the database on the Summary page in JobFrame. When i do this, i call the method in my database called PopulateSummary. Now, the reason i know my code is 100% correct.. is because i did the same thing in JobFrame for Validation to make sure code that was Aplha was not Numerical as well.. and if it was incorrect i would alter the label and that worked fine. why wont it work now?

```
public class Database 


           public void populateSummary()
{
    JobFrame info = new JobFrame();
    CoPrjGUI list = new CoPrjGUI();
    try
    {
    String text = list.txtField.getText();
    String query = "Select * from flooring where CustomerName like '" + text + "%'"; // Just need to adjust this to query only for search
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    if (rs.next())
    {
        String name = rs.getString("CustomerName");
        String address = rs.getString("CustomerAddress");
        String floorType = rs.getString("FlooringType");
        String floorArea = String.valueOf(rs.getDouble("FloorArea"));
        String floorCost = String.valueOf(rs.getDouble("FloorCost"));

        info.lblCustNameResult.setText(name); // Not writing to label. Why?
        info.lblAddressResult.setText(address);
        info.lblFlooringTypeResult.setText(floorType);
        info.lblSQFTResult.setText(floorArea);
        info.lblCostResult.setText(floorCost);
        String test = "Name: "+ name + "\n Address: "+ address + "\n Floor Type: "+ floorType + "\n floorArea: "
                + floorArea + "\n floorCost: " + floorCost;
        System.out.println(test);
    }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

public class JobFrame

```
static JLabel lblCustNameResult = new JLabel("New label");
static JLabel lblAddressResult = new JLabel("New label");
static JLabel lblPhoneResult = new JLabel("New label");
static JLabel lblDateResult = new JLabel("New label");
static JLabel lblFlooringTypeResult = new JLabel("New label");
static JLabel lblSQFTResult = new JLabel("New label");
static JLabel lblCostResult = new JLabel("New label");
JButton btnSaveInfo = new JButton("Save Info");
static JButton btnExport = new JButton("Export");
JTabbedPane TabHolder = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);




       btnSaveInfo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            String fullName = txtFirstName.getText() + " " + txtLastName.getText();
            String regexName = "[a-zA-Z]+";
            lblCustNameResult.setText(fullName);
            if (txtFirstName.getText().matches(regexName) || txtLastName.getText().matches(regexName))
            {
                lblCustNameResult.setText(fullName);
                EnableButton(); 
            }
            else
            {
                TabHolder.setSelectedIndex(0);
                txtFirstName.setText("Letters Only");
                txtLastName.setText("Letters Only");
                DisableButton();
            }

            String Address = txtStreetAddress.getText() + " " + txtCity.getText()
            + "\n" + " " + txtZip.getText() + " " + txtState.getText();
            lblAddressResult.setText(Address);
            /* //Need Individual Errors for each Text Box
            String regexAdress = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
            if (Address.equals(Address))
            {
                lblAddressResult.setText(Address);
                EnableButton();
            }
            else
            {
                TabHolder.setSelectedIndex(0);
                txtStreetAddress.setText("Example: 123 John Street ");
                txtCity.setText("Example: Dallas");
                txtZip.setText("Example: 75063");
                txtState.setText("Example: Texas");
                DisableButton();
            }
            */
            if (txtPhone.getText().matches("\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}"))
            {
                lblPhoneResult.setText(txtPhone.getText());
                EnableButton();
            }
            else 
            {
                txtPhone.setText("Valid Phone Format: 123-456-7890");
                TabHolder.setSelectedIndex(0);
                DisableButton();
            }

            String date = txtDate.getText();
            if (date.matches("\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}"))
            {
                lblDateResult.setText(txtDate.getText());
                EnableButton();
            }
            else
            {
                TabHolder.setSelectedIndex(0);
                txtDate.setText("yyyy/dd/mm");
                DisableButton();
            }

            if (fullName != "New Label" && fullName != "Letters Only")
            {
                if (Address != "New LabeL")
                {
                    if (txtPhone.getText() !=  "New Label" && txtPhone.getText().matches("\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}"))
                    {
                        if (date != "New Label" && date != "yyyy/dd/mm")
                        {
                            EnableButton();
                        }
                        else
                            DisableButton();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

}

public class CoPrjGUI

```
    JButton btnFind = new JButton("Find");
    btnFind.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            try {
                connect.ConnectToMyDB();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            connect.getData();
            for (Object item : connect.listInfo)
            {
                lstSearchResults.addItem(item);
            }
        }
    });

    JButton btnDownload = new JButton("Download");
    btnDownload.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {

            for (Object item : connect.listInfo)
            {
                cmbDownloads.addItem(item);
            }
            tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);
        }
    });


  JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            HomeFrame.setVisible(false);
            JobFrame CustFrame = new JobFrame();
            CustFrame.CustomerFrame.setVisible(true);
            CustFrame.setIndex();
            CustFrame.DisableButton(); 
            connect.populateSummary();
            txtField.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: show code for jframe please

Comment: From the snippet you provided from JobFrame, it looks like your JLabels should say "New label" yet in your screenshot they are blank. Are you sure you actually added these labels to your frame anywhere?

Comment: `im 100% sure the code is correct` - then the code will work, so obviously the code is not correct. `Ive tried changing them to static`- that is NOT a solution and should not be used. `change the text of a label doesnt seem to work` - if the code is executed and the label is visible on the frame then it will work. If it doesn't work, then the code is not executed or the label is not visible on the frame. Maybe you defined the label twice. The code you posted doesn't help because it doesn't show how you created the frame or the context of when your code is executed.

Comment: @camickr when they don't provide a section of code because it's "guarenteed 100% correct", that missing section is ALWAYS what's wrong :^)

Comment: If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Since we don't have access to your database the `SSCCE` would use hardcoded data in the method to change the labels. Start with a simple SSCCE. That is create a frame with a label and a button. When you click the button the label will be changed. Once this simple example works determine what is different between the SSCCE and your current code.

Comment: @BoDidely agreed :), which is why including a proper SSCCE/MCVE is the only way to post code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem : Had to call ConnectToMyDB() again and it worked fine..